# migrated .net core 2.2 app to 3.1 and it won't serve up in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have everything working locally, I have updated my build/deploy pipeline in Azure Dev Ops and everything builds and deploys fine however, when I call the site on my app service I get this error:
[image]

I have tried to find on the app service configuration page the place to change the .net core version (found this resource: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdatingAnASPNETCore22WebSiteToNETCore31LTS.aspx) but I don't see any place to change the version - just the stack type.  See 2nd screenshot:
[image]

Where do I need to go to update this to version 3.1?  All other searches I"ve tried are coming up empty.

Comment: How did you publish the artifacts locally? Choosing 32 bit application pool requires you to generate 32 bit artifacts for in-process mode hosting.

Comment: I didn't "publish" anything locally.  What I meant by "works locally" is that all of the modifications to my code, package updates etc work when debugging the application.

Comment: FWIW, I changed to 64 bit and seeing the same error.

Comment: You can read from Scott Hanselman's blog post many interesting details (self-contained deployment, linux-x64 and so on). As you didn't reveal your actual pipeline, it will be hard to comment further.

Comment: Did you add the .NET Core 3.1 extension? Azure app service doesn't support .NET Core 3.1 out of the box in all the regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that the [`ASP.NET Core Extensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#monitoring-blades) are installed. If the extensions aren't installed, install them manually:

1.In the `DEVELOPMENT TOOLS` blade section, select the `Extensions` blade.
2.The `ASP.NET Core Extensions` should appear in the list.
3.If the extensions aren't installed, select the `Add` button.
4.Choose the `ASP.NET Core Extensions` from the list.
5.Select `OK` to accept the legal terms.
6.Select OK on the Add extension blade.
7.An informational pop-up message indicates when the extensions are successfully installed.

After install `ASP.NET Core 3.1(x64) Runtime` Extension, then you will load your webapp successfully. Refer to this [article](https://amanagrawal.blog/2019/12/26/migrating-asp-net-core-2-2-app-to-asp-net-core-3-1-on-azure-app-services/) to migrate from 2.2 to 3.1.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer!  Thanks Joey!